# How to write an async concat with Entity Framework core?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a .NET 6 project.

Following is my query:

```
var data = await _context.Claims.AsNoTracking()                                     
.Where(cl=>cl.Contract.User.Email==email)
                            .Select(cl=>new ClaimDTO
                                                {
                                                id=cl.id,
                                                desc=cl.desc
                                                })                            
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Here is my 2nd query:

```
var data2 = await _context.HistoricalClaims.AsNoTracking()                                     
.Where(cl=>cl.Contract.User.Email==email)
                            .Select(cl=>new ClaimDTO
                                                {
                                                id=cl.id,
                                                desc=cl.desc
                                                })                            
                            .ToListAsync();
```

I want to learn how to do UNION ALL at SQL server and at client.

Here is my code to try and do it on the SQL server:

```
var data = await _context.Claims.AsNoTracking()                                     
.Where(cl=>cl.Contract.User.Email==email)
                            .Select(cl=>new ClaimDTO
                                                {
                                                id=cl.id,
                                                desc=cl.desc
                                                })                            
               .Concat(await _context.HistoricalClaims.AsNoTracking()                                     
               .Where(cl=>cl.Contract.User.Email==email)
                            .Select(cl=>new ClaimDTO
                                                {
                                                id=cl.id,
                                                desc=cl.desc
                                                })  
                                     )
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Can someone correct my query to perform the union all on the sql server.

Secondly, assuming I run the 2 separate queries and response is held in data and data1 variables, then is the following correct syntax? `vat result = data.Concat(data1);`

Comment: I assume you're using EF Core?

Comment: yes that right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close. The `await` inside the `Concat()` isn't needed.

```cs
var items = await context.Items
    .Where(w => w.ItemNo == 4)
    .Select(s => new Dto { Name = s.Desc, Num = s.ItemNo })
    .Concat(
        context.ItemsHistory
            .Where(w => w.ItemNo == 4)
            .Select(s => new Dto { Name = s.Desc, Num = s.ItemNo })
        )
    .ToListAsync();
```

Results in this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT [i].[Desc] AS [Name], [i].[ItemNo] AS [Num]
FROM [Items] AS [i]
WHERE [i].[ItemNo] = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT [i0].[Desc] AS [Name], [i0].[ItemNo] AS [Num]
FROM [ItemsHistory] AS [i0]
WHERE [i0].[ItemNo] = 4
```

Regarding your second question: yes, after materializing you can concat two lists together as long as the types are compatible with each other:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
       IEnumerable<TSource> second)
```

Comment: Small comment, don't put everywhere `AsNoTracking()`. EF Core do not track entities created by `Select`

Comment: Thanks! I've removed it